# How to set up an attempts counter in a function bound to a button?

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, tkinter, counter

I have been trying to set up a login screen, and been stuck at this specific problem for the last 2 days. For the sake of clarity and ease of use, I wanted to define a function that would keep track of the number of attempts at wrong username-pass combo and bound that function to the enter button. I tried while loops as well as basic if x = x AND attempt < y: styles but neither worked. After searching for a similar question I found out an answer that advised the use of for loop which seems to make more sense both visually and practically. When I enter a wrong pass combo and press enter, I instantly get the access denied message instead of the left attempts. I suspect that the loop is repeating itself without the press of enter button and finishing the attempts in one go.

```
def checkname():
    attempt = 4
    for attempt in range(attempt,0,-1):
        usern = entry_name.get()
        passw = entry_pass.get()

        if (usern, passw) in names:
            message.configure(text = "Access Granted!")
        else:
            message.configure(text = "{0} attempts left".format(attempt) )
    else:
        message.configure(text="Access Denied!")
```

I thought about making a global variable outside of the function and make sure it keeps track of the attempts but it seems to give unbound local variable error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You get the unbound local error because of omitting the global declaration as in Bryan's answer, which is +- the same as I started writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a loop since a tkinter GUI already has a loop running (`mainloop`). Just increment a global variable in your function, and stop when the number gets too big:

```
...
login_button = tk.Button(..., command=do_login)
...

attempts = 0

def do_login():
    global attempts
    attempts = attempts + 1
    if attempts > 4:
        <code to handle too many attempts>
    else
        <code to handle an attempt>
```

Of course, if you are using classes, make `attempts` be an attribute on a class rather than a global variable.